# Find the order between two substrings in lua

Tags: string, lua, substring

If I were to have the following string

```lua
local test = "randomrandomrandomrandomONErandomrandomrandomrandomTWOrandomrandom"
```

How would I be able to tell the text "ONE" or "TWO" came first in the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `find` which returns 2 values:

- the position where the first word found is starting
- the position where the first word found is ending

```
test = "randomrandomrandomrandomONErandomrandomrandomrandomTWOrandomrandom"

if test:find("ONE") < test:find("TWO") then
  print("ONE is before TWO")
else
  print("TWO is before ONE")
end
```

Should display:

```
ONE is before TWO
```

Regarding the function `find`:

```
> test = "randomrandomrandomrandomONErandomrandomrandomrandomTWOrandomrandom"
> Start, End = test:find("ONE")
25      27
```

In this particular case, `Start` will get the value `25` and `End` will get the value `27`.